# Build project deletes lib file

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I am building `SOFA Framework on VS2010`, The solution consist of 68 Projects,
An amazing thing happend that `for instance`, If I build Project `A`, it generates `A.lib` file in lib folder,When I build Project `B`,it generates `B.lib` in the lib folder and deletes `A.lib`,The problem is that Project `C` depends upon both `lib files` so i can't build it,It always gives me linking Error that It can't open `A.lib` Or `B.lib`
Anyone who can help me with this..
Thanks

Comment: Never heard that before try to check that Application experience service is started in cPanel

Comment: @ZainShah120 it is started and set to manual...

Comment: That is very odd. Project dependencies, I assume, are setup correctly; I.e. C-->A, C-->B, and B-->A. It almost sounds like C is not in a dependency chain, but that would not necessarily explain the B-built-and-toasted-A's-lib scenario you're describing.

Comment: Yes that is strange,The lib shouldn't be deleted in any case..

Comment: Long shot, but you might also check that there isn't anything in the pre-build or post-build event command lines for each project that's screwing around with the contents of the Lib folder.  Happened to me once on a big solution.